# how to use doInBackground in android for show error msg

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Hello i am using AsyncTask for webservice calling. Its working fine when i enter correct username and password, when i enter wrong then its how msg wrong username and password but in my code in doInBackground area its throw expction or application crass
private class LoginTask extends AsyncTask {

```
    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(login.this); 

    protected void onPreExecute() { 

            this.dialog.setMessage("Logging in..."); 
            this.dialog.show(); 
    } 


    protected Void doInBackground(final Void... unused) { 
        String auth=calllogin(Username,Passowrd); 
        cls_constant.userid=auth;
        if(auth.equals("0"))
        {

        TextView errorTextview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_error);
        errorTextview.setText("Username & Password incorrect.");
        }
        else {

        Intent intnt=new Intent(getBaseContext(), aftersignin.class);
        startActivity(intnt);
        }
        return null; // don't interact with the ui! 
    } 


    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)  
    { 

            if (this.dialog.isShowing()) 
            { 
            this.dialog.dismiss(); 
            }


     }
```

i want ot show error mgs like this but i dont know whats i m doing wrong 
or how to use onPostExecute for show msg 
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant update *TextView* on a different thread (since Asyn does job in a new thread) since it belongs to UI thread. So fix your **doInBackground** as below:

```
protected Void doInBackground(final Void... unused) { 
    String auth=calllogin(Username,Passowrd); 
    cls_constant.userid=auth;
    if(auth.equals("0"))
    {
      YourActivityClass.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            TextView errorTextview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_error);
                errorTextview.setText("Username & Password incorrect.");
        }
      });
    }
    else {

    Intent intnt=new Intent(getBaseContext(), aftersignin.class);
    startActivity(intnt);
    }
    return null; // don't interact with the ui! 
}
```

Comment: where i do change this i dont get i m new in android

Comment: I just updated my answer. Replace **YourActivityClass** with your Activity class' name

Comment: Why would you do that when you have `onPostExecute()` right there for you to use that runs ont he UI thread for you?

Comment: because he wanted to know the problem, and i've pointed the problem with a fix. Though he is dismissing dialog on postExecute but its up to him how codes  :)

Comment: `AsyncTask` was designed for this exact purpose of separating between background threads and UI threads in an easy way. Since he's new to android, you should have shown him the proper way of doing it rather than any solution that just happens to work. Anyways. I hope he reads other solutions below since a few ppl below posted the actual proper way to do this within the android framework.

Comment: Dont you think he also learnt something new from this answer that views can only be changed on UI thread??? so take it easy bro, we are here to help, not to fight for points  :)

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty much done with your AsyncTask by the time you get to `if(auth.equals("0"))`, so you could move that whole block into `onPostExecute()`.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot touch anything in the ui from a background thread (like async tasks) 
The correct way to do is using a handler, when auth.equals("0") you must call that handler and update the ui from there...

```
if(auth.equals("0")){
    Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
    msg.what = "error";
    msg.obj = "Username & Password incorrect.";
    handler.sendMessage(msg);
}
```

in the ui thread:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler(){
  @Override
  public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    if(msg.what==error){
      TextView errorTextview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_error);
      errorTextview.setText(msg.what.toString());
    }
    super.handleMessage(msg);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way to do it, with no runOnUiThread or Handler extra code. Capture the error/success in `doInBackground()` then in `onPostExecute()` update the TextView or start the activity accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The `onPostExecute` is there to help you out. So you might as well use it.

The problem is that `doInBackgoround` is not running on the UI thread. However `onPostExecute` is. So it's there to help you out.

Change your AsyncTask to something like this

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

  onPreExecute(....)

  protected Boolean doInBackground(final Void... unused) {
     String auth=calllogin(Username,Passowrd); 
     cls_constant.userid=auth;
     if(auth.equals("0")) 
        return false;
     else
        return true;
  }

  protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) { 
     if (this.dialog.isShowing()) 
        this.dialog.dismiss(); 

     if (!result) { 
        TextView errorTextview=(TextView)MyActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.tv_error);
        errorTextview.setText("Username & Password incorrect.");
     } else {
        Intent intnt=new Intent(getBaseContext(), aftersignin.class);
        MyActivity.this.startActivity(intnt);
  } 
}
```